# Name of the Navigation Portlet on Plone.org?

Tags: plone

What is the name of the collapsing Navigation Portlet on [Plone.org](http://www.plone.org) (Get Plone - Learn Plone - Get Involved)? I can't find it in the Portlets Download Section.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a portlet, but part of the custom Plone.org frontpage view that uses the [jQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) widget.

See the [Plone.org frontpage source](https://github.com/plone/Products.PloneOrg/blob/master/src/Products/PloneOrg/skins/ploneorg/frontpage.pt).

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <h2 class="current">Get Plone</h2>


    <div class="pane" style="display:block">
        <a id="download-link" href="/download">DOWNLOAD NOW<br />
            Plone 
            <span tal:content="python: here.products.getFeaturedProjectRelease().getId()">3.2.0</span>
            &middot; 
            <span tal:content="python: here.products.getFeaturedProjectRelease().effective_date.strftime('%h ' + u'\u2019' + '%y')">Feb 2009</span></a>
        <dl>
            <dt><a href="/products/plone/features/">What’s new in Plone 4</a></dt>
            <dd>An overview of the new features.</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://plone.org/roadmap">Roadmap</a></dt>
            <dd>Our plans for the future.</dd>

            <dt><a href="/products/plone/releases">Older releases</a></dt>
            <dd>Looking for a previous version?</dd>

            <dt><a href="/products">Add-on Products</a></dt>
            <dd>Adapt Plone to your needs.</dd>

            <dt><a href="/products/plone/security/advisories">Security Advisories</a></dt>
        </dl>
    </div>  

    <h2>Learn Plone</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        <dl>
            <dt><a href="/documentation">Documentation</a></dt>
            <dd>Plone has a great collection of online documentation.</dd>

            <dt><a href="/documentation/books">Buy Books</a></dt>
            <dd>For those of you who think better in bed with a book.</dd>

            <dt><a href="/support">Forums &amp; Chat Rooms</a></dt>
            <dd>People are always ready to help you with your Plone questions.</dd>

            <dt><a href="/events/training">Find Plone Training</a></dt>
            <dd>Let one of the Plone experts guide you through getting productive.</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://plone.net">Commercial Support</a></dt>
            <dd>Over 300 companies around the world offer Plone services.</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

    <h2>Get Involved</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        <dl>
            <dt><a href="http://plone.org/documentation/faq/suggest-a-feature-for-plone">Suggest New Features</a></dt>
            <dd>Have an awesome idea about a new feature for Plone?</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://dev.plone.org/plone">Report Bugs</a></dt>
            <dd>Plone has no bugs. If you found one anyway, report it here.</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://dev.plone.org/plone">Write Code</a></dt>
            <dd>If you’re proficient in Python, HTML, CSS or JS, join us!</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://dev.plone.org/plone">Translate, Write Docs, Help Test</a></dt>
            <dd>There are lots of things you can do to make Plone better.</dd>

            <dt><a href="http://planet.plone.org">Read Blogs, Publish Yours</a></dt>
            <dd>Stay up to date on Plone</dd>

            <dt><a href="/foundation">Support the Plone Foundation</a></dt>
            <dd>If all else fails, give cold, hard cash.</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>

</div> <!-- End accordion -->
```

Comment: @user1964699: Could this answer help you further or are you still experiencing difficulties?